# PrimeVue Menubar CSS question - align right but with a dynamically changing button to the left of menu items

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, flexbox, primevue

I have a requirement where I want to use the PrimeVue Menubar component but modify such that the menu items (links) are aligned to the right of the menu and I need to pass in a button called Versions to be displayed to the left of the first menu link. I need the Versions button to be positioned to just the left of the first menu link regardless of how many or how few menu links there are.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ri3da8?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FNavBar.vue

The only way I have been able to align the menu links to the right has been through `margin-left: auto;`. I tried using flex/justify-content end but that doesn't seem to work in this template.

Setting the menu links `margin-left: auto` makes it so I am not able to position the Versions button where I want unless I use position absolute which I don't want to use because it would not be dynamic.